# Replace identity column from int to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008, and I have a table that contains about 50 mill rows.

That table contains a primary identity column of type `int`.

I want to upgrade that column to be `bigint`.

I need to know how to do that in a quick way that will not make my DB server unavailable,
and will not delete or ruin any of my data

How should I best do it ? what are the consequences of doing that?

Comment: It is not just this table itself; it is every table that has a FK relationship into this column that needs to be locked. You are only at about 2.5% of MAXINT; is this a pressing issue, or just "being prepared"

Comment: **WHY?!?!** A column of type `INT` gives you **2 billion** rows! That's more than 40 times the amount you're using right now. How quickly are you using those numbers? Most likely, this `INT` columns is still **WAY** more than enough for your system for a looooooooong time to come!

Comment: It is being prepared to what will come on the following weeks... i must do it... so, what is the best way to do so ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, it won't be a quick'n'easy way to do this, really....

My approach would be this:

1. create a new table with identical structure - except for the `ID` column being `BIGINT IDENTITY` instead of `INT IDENTITY`

   ----[ put your server into exclusive single-user mode here; user cannot use your server from this point on ]----
2. find and disable all foreign key constraints referencing your table
3. turn `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your new table) ON`
4. insert the rows from your old table into the new table
5. turn `SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your new table) OFF`
6. delete your old table
7. rename your new table to the old table name
8. update all table that have a FK reference to your table to use `BIGINT` instead of `INT` (that should be doable with a simple `ALTER TABLE ..... ALTER COLUMN FKID BIGINT`)
9. re-create all foreign key relationships again
10. now you can return your server to normal multi-user usage again

Comment: Note: this cannot be done without either (1) making the server unavailable from step 2 to 9; or (2) potentially making all data modifications during the change over invalid because of the absence of FK lookups and validation.

Comment: What will happened if i will stop the access to the DB, to the the table=>edit , change the column type to bigint and press save ?

Comment: @MatanL: then the visual designer in SQL Server Mgmt Studio will attempt to create the new table, copy the data over, drop the old table, rename the new table to the old name - but it will fail if there are any FK references on your table. As I said in the beginning of my response: this is **NOT** a *quick'n'easy* change you're thinking about here! So again: **WHY** do you even consider this? `INT` has **plenty** of values for your database!

Comment: i am working on a project that should deal these numbers very soon... the problem is that i am using the identity of the row for the entire project and some rows are deleted one in a while... so re-inserting all the data to a new table will cause differect information for me...

Comment: @MatanL: if you use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` then you will insert **the very same ID values** into your new table!

Comment: When you say "delete your old table", would that mean to DROP the table? If so, I can not make this work, as I get the error message: "Could not drop object 'dbo.TableName' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint." Even after all the FKs are disabled.

Comment: @PetterT: yes - drop the table. If you can't because of FK constraints, you have to **drop** those FK constraints, too (drop - not merely disable) and then re-create them after you've created the new table

Comment: @marc_s, thanks, dropping the FK constraints made it work.

Answer (score 20):

What am I missing?

Why can't you just do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN ID bigint
```

I guess try it in a test environment first but this always works for me

Comment: I just tried it and you can.  Thanks for posting this because after reading the above answers I wasn't going to try it.  It works just fine and preserves the seed for the identity column.

Comment: This question came to my mind while I was creating a new table in my db today. Even I thought that just an ALTER statement should do. Searched  and the answers above tells me it isn't that easy. I am *guessing* that this statement will work just fine if there are no FK references, constraints on the table but will fail otherwise. I will probably try this sometime later on a test db and post the results.

Comment: Ah interesting never thought if the FK scenario. Please let me know!

Comment: The points you are missing are 1) What if the table has huge number of records this query will run for ever and also increasing the mdf/ldf file sizes 2) Handling FK scenarios.

Comment: @willsteel In the case of FKs you can: **1)** Drop them. **2)** Change the column in the main table. **3)** Change the columns in the dependent tables (that had the FK) to BIGINT. **4)** Recreate the FKs (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002330/4850646, it's about MySQL but should behave the same way). About a table with too many rows I think that when a table reach 1 million rows such a change should be thought about to avoid inconveniences later, otherwise even the accepted answer might not avoid downtime. You can make your DB read-only in this period tough, to avoid total downtime.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the best way is to create a new table with a BIGINT IDENTITY column, move the existing data using SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON; and then rename the tables. You will need to do this during a maintenance window, just as you would if you changed the data type in Management Studio (which would similarly create a new table, move the data, and block everyone in the process).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Alter script for your column as @MobileMon said, but couldn't do this before removing constraints. And besides FK constraints, you must also remove PK constraint before changing the column type!

Also there is another creative way, if the ID data is not important (No FK etc):

1. Take a Backup of table (if it's in a separate FileGroup) or DB
2. Rename table (Having no more inserts)
3. Remove PK/Constraints from the column
4. Drop ID column
5. Add new ID column, with Identity
6. Apply PK
7. Rename table back to original name (back to work :) )

& If the ID data is important:

1. Step 1,2 like above
2. Create a new column
3. Transfer the data from the existing IDENTITY column to the new column
4. Drop the existing IDENTITY column & PK.
5. Make new column, with Identity
6. Apply PK
7. Rename table back to original name (back to work :) )

Important Note: 1. If the old column ID value in not important & there are big gaps between your values(you have deletes besides inserts), you don't need BigInt. Just make the new ID column as Int again.
2. When table grows & is reaching Overflow value(2 billion) you could look at the actual row number in properties, storage of your table. Maybe your reaching overflow, but your row number is much less than that.

Answer (score -4):

Why would someone want to use a BigInt instead of Int as an IDENTITY?

Consider this scenario:
Your database exists in several environments including 1 instance in a live Production environment and several other instances in (TestA, B, C, etc.), (QA A, B, C, etc.), (Demo A, B, C, etc),  (UAT A, B, C, etc.), (Training A, B, C, etc.) on and on and on... You don't even want to know...

This database IDENTITY field is used to pass in an unique number to a 3rd party provider which is a shared environment in the Non Production environments.  The vendor charges an arm and a leg in order to set up multiple environments so the company has one for the production DB and one for ALL the others.

So... when testing happens in the non production environments these numbers can never cross each other from whatever non production environment you happen to be testing in.  And the testing includes stress testing... sending 100's of thousands of rows at a time.

To top it off... ALL these environments get refreshed with Production so the Identity field gets reset with whatever was in production.  So one has to keep track of what spread was used in each environment and then reset the IDENTITY to a new spread that has never been used before.  The 3rd party vendor will puke if an already number gets sent again in these environments.  And the vendor is unwilling or unable to refresh or reset these numbers on their end.

This is a real world issue and the current field remains to be an int in ALL environments and the management of keeping track of these spreads is updated every quarter or whenever someone does a massive stress testing 100's of thousands of transactions.

So in about 10 years this IDENTITY will have to be updated to a BIGINT or someone will have to convince the 3rd party vendor to refresh on their end.

Oh yeah, management could give a rat's ass about it until everything comes crashing down all of a sudden.

Then the HACK "ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN ID bigint" will do just fine.
Space and index processing is CHEAP!

Comment: How about FK?  Will they have to be changed to bigint too?

Comment: While this is OK for WHY NOT, the question is HOW TO and to quote you "So in about 10 years..." OK, ten years is up, 2.7B rows exist, time to march the march.

Comment: There was another question too, what are the consequences of doing that?

Comment: "Consequences schmonsequences, as long as I'm rich! "  was the attitude of management at that previous engagement.   Myopia is almost as common as inflated egos in this industry.