# How to handle auto number (index) on large amount of data?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table on my database (SQL Server 2014) and it has a auto number column as my index column.

I have a lot of data insertions on a day and i was thinking how can i handle my db after a year , I mean that auto number column are limited to a number at last.

If i need to change my database's  architecture or design , where can i 
    found the reference to do it?

Comment: What is your actual question here? The maximum number of rows in your table? What reference are you looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql server's `int` data type top limit is `2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)`.
Even if you insert `100,000` rows per day, it would take more then 50 years to reach the max limit. I'm guessing in that time, should your application live that long, sql server 2014 would be so outdated that someone will re-write the application at least once.
If you don't think that's enough, you can use `BigInt` data type, that has a top limit of  `2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)`.

Also, note that nothing is stopping you from using the negative numbers as well, and if you do this, you have a range of `4,294,967,296` for a regular `int`. That's going to be very hard to use up in any application lifetime.

From the relevant [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx):

```
Data type   Range                                                                       Storage
bigint      -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)    8 Bytes
int         -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)                            4 Bytes
smallint    -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)                                          2 Bytes
tinyint     0 to 255                                                                    1 Byte
```

Comment: increasing index column from negative numbers is a good idea or not?

Comment: I don't see a downside for this.

Answer (score 2):

your ever increasing column is probably an `INT` which has a limit of  `2,147,483,647`..If you are sure ,your table can grow beyond this number

Then try `BIGINT` which has a limit of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` and read as 
*nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six*

Here is how you can change an Identity column from INT to BIGINT

[Replace identity column from int to bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277804/replace-identity-column-from-int-to-bigint)

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like `int` is going to be too small for the primary key (max 2,147,483,647), try using `bigint` (9,223,372,036,854,775,807). That should be sufficient for most of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a primary key, likely the clustered index.  Using Identity is a standard practice as this will put new records 'at the end'.  You will want other indexes for other queries.

As for a limitation, the bar is pretty high.

```
Data type   Range   Storage
bigint  -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)    8 Bytes
int -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)    4 Byte
```