# Convert an existing Identity column to sequence

Tags: sql-server, sequence, identity

Existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Airlines_Mast]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_ID]  AS ('AS'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)
```

Created sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [Airlines_Mast_SEQ]
AS INTEGER
START WITH 3
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 99999;
```

Existing identity column:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL

[ID] [INT] DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR [Airlines_Mast_SEQ] PRIMARY KEY
```

How to convert an existing identity column to using a sequence?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. You must create the new column as desired and then drop the old one - while also managing the constraints and indexing.

Answer (score 2):

If your original table has a primary key constraint like the new one, you can use `SWITCH` to move data to a new table with the same schema (including indexes). The `IDENTITY` property meta-data will not be retained. You just need to ensure the sequence `START WTIH` values is higher than the existing `MAX(ID)` value

For Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [Airlines_Mast_SEQ]
    AS INTEGER
    START WITH 3
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 99999; 
CREATE TABLE dbo.Airlines_Mast
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Airlines_ID]  AS ('AS'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Airlines_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Airlines_Mast (Airlines_Name) VALUES (N'example1');
INSERT INTO dbo.Airlines_Mast (Airlines_Name) VALUES (N'example2');
SELECT * FROM dbo.Airlines_Mast;
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRAN;
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Airlines_Mast_Sequence]
    (
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR [Airlines_Mast_SEQ] PRIMARY KEY,
        [Airlines_ID]  AS ('AS'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar],[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
        [Airlines_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
    );
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Airlines_Mast
        SWITCH TO dbo.Airlines_Mast_Sequence;
    DROP TABLE dbo.Airlines_Mast;
    EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.Airlines_Mast_Sequence',N'Airlines_Mast';
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Airlines_Mast (Airlines_Name) VALUES (N'example3');
SELECT * FROM dbo.Airlines_Mast;
```

Results:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+
| ID | Airlines_ID | Airlines_Name |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | AS000001    | example1      |
|  2 | AS000002    | example2      |
+----+-------------+---------------+

+----+-------------+---------------+
| ID | Airlines_ID | Airlines_Name |
+----+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | AS000001    | example1      |
|  2 | AS000002    | example2      |
|  3 | AS000003    | example3      |
+----+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: how to do switch for a master table  which has 3 details and relation was made by this ID column?

Comment: @ZedZip, `SWITCH` (like `TRUNCATE`) is not permitted when the table is referenced by a foreign key constraint. Drop the related table FK constraints before the switch and recreate the constraints after the rename.

Comment: How to use this script if I want to replace integer key with bigint?

Comment: @ZedZip, `SWITCH` requires identical schema to remove the identity so you'll need to change the `ID` column data type first, which in this case requires dropping the dependent primary key constraint and computed column and then recreating afterwards. After doing that, the only change to the script is the data type of the sequence and `ID` column in the new table.

Comment: Thank you Dan, but anyway: I hope the SWITCH somehow can be used . I have a large table (100 000 000 rows) with PK identity which was reset and now goes from -mixint -> 0. And soon it will reach 0 and database stopped. How to use switch for fast ? :-)

Comment: @ZedZip, I don't think SWITCH will help for your scenario. Create and load a new table as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277804/replace-identity-column-from-int-to-bigint). You could engineer a solution specific to your scenario to reduce the maintenance window like loading historical read-only data first, and then load a final delta of new/updated rows.

Comment: Alas, Ok, thank you